# Python - Replace entries in list with a common pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a python list of different URLs. I am trying to extract the domain names out of that.

```
list1 = ['wwww.google.com.my','www.yahoo.co.jp','www.facebook.com']
```

I am trying to convert the above such that the final output is as below:

```
list1 = ['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com','www.facebook.com']
```

Comment: That is an invalid syntax for list in Python.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your piece of code.

Comment: Try searching up on regular expressions.

Comment: How exactly does `www.yahoo.co.jp` turn into `www.yahoo.com`?

Comment: I'm wondering where you got those URLs from. A domain ending in ".my"? www.yahoo.co.jp is probably a valid domain for the Japanese branch of Yahoo, so why switch that to .com?

Comment: The domain name in `wwww.google.com.my` is `google.com.my`.

Comment: @scott martin, see if the answer postd below helps?

Comment: @scott martin, you may consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `.com` and concatenate with a `.com`, since it is assumed that you want them all to end like that:

```
list1 = ['wwww.google.com.my','www.yahoo.co.jp','www.facebook.com']

print([e.split(".co")[0] + ".com" for e in list1])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['wwww.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.facebook.com']
```

Comment: Wow, really? A solution that only works for `.com`/`.co` urls?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Indeed. looking at the question. Since the OP wants  `www.yahoo.co.jp` to `www.yahoo.com`. How else would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to change `.co` into `.com` (why would you?), you might try:

```
list2 = ['.'.join(url.split('.')[:3]) for url in list1]
```

Comment: returns `www.yahoo.co` instead of `'www.yahoo.com'`

Comment: I know. I wrote that, in my opinion, there's no need to change it into `.com` since `.co` is still a valid domain. I'm waiting for the OP to clarify on this

Comment: Indeed. but not the output OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to parse the input and build the actual outcome you desire.

For example, this regex finds the domain and plants it in a www.**domain**.com pattern, there are lot's of other patterns to use that can work.

```
import re
list2 = [re.sub(r'w*\.?(\w+)\..*', r'www.\1.com', x) for x in list1]
```

Comment: This prints `['wwww.google.com.my', 'www.yahoo.co.jp', 'www.facebook.com']`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer, swapped \W with \w so that the period won't be swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a few more urls in the list to tackle all different types possible,

```
list1 = ['wwww.google.com.my','www.yahoo.co.jp','www.facebook.com',
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/','https://google.co.in',
'https://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/','www.stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/']
```

The code is as follows,

```
new_list=[]

list1 = ['wwww.google.com.my','www.yahoo.co.jp','www.facebook.com',
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/','https://google.co.in',
'https://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/','www.stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/']

for item in list1:
    if(item[:4]!='http'):
        url1='www.'+item.split(".")[1]+'.com'
        if(item.split('/')[0])==item:
            new_list.append(url1)
        else:
            length=len(item.split('/'))
            url2=''
            for i in range(1,length):
                url2=url2+'/'+item.split('/')[i]
            url1=url1+url2
            new_list.append(url1)
    if(item[:4]=='http'):
        url1='www.'+item.split('://')[1]
        url1='www.'+url1.split('.')[1]+'.com'
        if(item.split('/'))[2]==item[8:]:
            new_list.append(url1)
        else:
            length=len(item.split('/'))
            url2=''
            for i in range(3,length):
                url2=url2+'/'+item.split('/')[i]
            url1=url1+url2
            new_list.append(url1)
```

The `new_list` in the above code is to be considered as output, and is as follows,

```
In [1]:new_list
Out[1]: 
['www.google.com',
 'www.yahoo.com',
 'www.facebook.com',
 'www.stackoverflow.com/questions/',
 'www.google.com',
 'www.stackoverflow.com/questions/',
 'www.stackoverflow.com/questions/']
```

Let me know if this works enough for you!

Edit: Since this a specific use-case based query there is no general solution, hence I've not addressed any addresses that uses `.gov` or `.edu` ,etc. Those use-cases can be appended to the code above as required. 
Also, this might change address and output a global `.com` url to a website which may not exist globally.